# How do query a table table using subquery or derived table?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Just started learning MySQL and I don't know yet how to properly execute complex queries.
I want to query a table that will show which customer spends the most and that will output this column:

```
+------------+----------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| year       | customername                                 | spend_amount                              |
+------------+----------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+
|2003        | must relate/tied to the values on the right  | highest value in existing in this row year|
|2004        | must relate/tied to the values on the right  | highest value in existing in this row year|
|2005        | must relate/tied to the values on the right  | highest value in existing in this row year|
+------------+-------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

However I keep getting

[image: this]

The query syntax I have is:

```
SELECT
DATE_FORMAT(orders.orderDate,'%Y') AS year, 
customers.customerName AS customername,
SUM(orderdetails.priceEach*orderdetails.quantityOrdered) AS 'spend_amount'
FROM
orders
INNER JOIN orderdetails USING (orderNumber)  
INNER JOIN customers USING (customerNumber)
WHERE orders.status not in('cancelled','disputed')
GROUP BY year, customerName
ORDER BY year ASC;
```

And I'm Trying to out a table similar to

[image: this]

UPDATE:
I was able to tweak the syntax and use sub-query below to solve my problem:

```
SELECT 
year,
customername,
spend_amount AS 'spend_amount'
FROM
 (SELECT
DATE_FORMAT(orders.orderDate,'%Y') AS year, 
customers.customerName AS customerName,
SUM(orderdetails.priceEach*orderdetails.quantityOrdered) AS 'spend_amount'
FROM
orders
INNER JOIN orderdetails USING (orderNumber)  
INNER JOIN customers USING (customerNumber)
WHERE orders.status = 'Shipped'
GROUP BY year, customerName
ORDER BY spend_amount DESC) asset_table
GROUP BY year
```

Comment: Simpy try ORDER BY year ASC,customername ASC;

Comment: I tried to add and update that on the last line but it still returned more than 3 rows for all the year